# How to request mobile site through iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a use case where I need to open a small iframe to Bing. It has a min-width property of 990px and I only have about 400px to work with, so I am trying to open it as a mobile site.

As far as I can tell, Bing looks at user agent to determine the site version it should serve. However, from my research it appears that it's not possible to give an iframe a custom user agent. Did I misunderstand? Or is there some other way to force mobile?

Bing is not responsive to just limiting the width of the frame, which is what everyone seems to give as the "answer" for this sort of question.

This is not a "fix my code" question - I am trying to find the right approach to this problem, and have not found any way to get what I want to happen.

Comment: Please share some code :D

Comment: @TomCupis All I have is `<iframe src="http://bing.com" width="400"></iframe>`. I'm looking for the right approach; I don't even know what to attempt that would produce the result I am looking for.